# Python any item from a list in another list

Tags: python

What is an elegant way to return a list of T/F for a list if matches a list of items?

For example:

```
[1,3,5,4]
in
[4,3,7,5,8]
```

Returns:

```
[True, True, False, True, False]
```

Comment: But `4` is also in your first list..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Testing membership](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) in a set is O(1), while testing membership in a list is O(n). So (especially for a big list) you should convert `firstlist` to a set before testing for membership.

```
firstset = set(firstlist)
[(v in firstset) for v in otherlist]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use List Comprehension: -

```
>>> list1 = [4, 3, 7, 5, 8]
>>> list2 = [1, 3, 5, 4]
>>> new_list = [elem in list2 for elem in list1]
>>> new_list
[True, True, False, True, False]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

By using a list comprehension:

```
[(v in firstlist) for v in otherlist]
```